# Laravel collection / blade - displaying unique rows

Tags: php, laravel, loops, laravel-blade, unique

Wasn't quite sure how to formulate the question, so I hope it represents my issue.

What I want to achieve is, displaying on my website's dashboard, for each user a list of meals for the upcoming week.

And in this example it will be 3 meals a day.

My database for this looks like this:

```
$table->id();
$table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained('users');
$table->enum('day', ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday']);
$table->foreignId('meal_id')->nullable()->constrained('food_meals');
$table->enum('type', ['breakfast', 'lunch', 'dinner']);
$table->string('slug')->unique();
$table->timestamps();
```

I have a simple relation setup in my `User model`:

```
public function userMeals()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Meal::class);
}
```

And the data returned to my dashboard is this:

```
$meals = auth()->user()->userMeals()->get();
```

When looping over the data in my blade, I of course get each day displayed three times:

[image: Blade loop]

But what I want of course is this:

[image: Blade loop 2]

And in my database I store the data like this:

[image: Database]

So 3 entries per day, based on the type of meal.

So basically my question is this. Can I have the data displayed in my blade file like I have on the second picture with this setup, so I can edit the data in my controller? Or is this bad design and should I go about it differently?

PS. When I do this for example, it works, but I can never display the initial data for the breakfast, lunch and dinner, because two entries for each day will be lost:

```
auth()->user()->userMeals()->get()->unique('day')
```

Comment: You'd have to loop over the Days (Monday through Sunday) and filter which rows to render based on the day and available database records. Show the code for your front-end rendering; you'd likely need some nested `foreach()` loops, like `@foreach($days as $day)`, then maybe `@foreach($types as $type)`, then finally `@foreach($meals->filter(function($meal) use ($day, $type) { return $meal->day == $day && $meal->type == $type); }) as $filteredMeal)` (or similar). You might be able to get your data in this format directly from a query, but `unique` wouldn't be correct; you'd need all 3 `types` 

Comment: $meals = auth()->user()->userMeals()->get()->groupBy(['day', 'type']);

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: `get()` returns a collection, so you can always use [Laravel's Collection class and methods](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections) to help rearrange re-class the results. For instance, there's a [groupBy method](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-groupby) that you can use to create sub arrays by day

Comment: Change your DB structure to make it much more flexible and streamlined. Move out the `day` and `type` columns to being individual tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define an attribute method on your `User.php` model:

```
public function getMealsGroupedByDayAndTypeAttribute()
{
    $grouped = [];
    $days = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday'];
    $types = ['breakfast', 'lunch', 'dinner'];

    foreach ($days as $day) {
        foreach ($types as $type) {
            $grouped[$day][$type] = $this->userMeals->where('day', $day)->where('type', $type)->first();
        }
    }

    return $grouped;
}
```

An example output of `auth()->user()->meals_grouped_by_day_and_type` will be like this:

```
[
    'monday' => [
        'breakfast' => [
            'id' => 1,
            'user_id' => 1,
            'day' => 'monday',
            'type' => 'breakfast',
            'meal_id' => 1,
            'created_at' => '2021-05-04T20:00:00.000000Z',
            'updated_at' => '2021-05-04T20:00:00.000000Z',
        ],
        'lunch' => [
            'id' => 2,
            'user_id' => 1,
            'day' => 'monday',
            'type' => 'lunch',
            'meal_id' => 2,
            'created_at' => '2021-05-04T20:00:00.000000Z',
            'updated_at' => '2021-05-04T20:00:00.000000Z',
        ],
        'dinner' => [
            'id' => 3,
            'user_id' => 1,
            'day' => 'monday',
            'type' => 'dinner',
            'meal_id' => 3,
            'created_at' => '2021-05-04T20:00:00.000000Z',
            'updated_at' => '2021-05-04T20:00:00.000000Z',
        ],
    ],
    'tuesday' => [
        'breakfast' => [
            'id' => 4,
            'user_id' => 1,
            'day' => 'tuesday',
            'type' => 'breakfast',
            'meal_id' => 4,
            'created_at' => '2021-05-04T20:00:00.000000Z',
            'updated_at' => '2021-05-04T20:00:00.000000Z',
        ],
        'lunch' => [
            'id' => 5,
            'user_id' => 1,
            'day' => 'tuesday',
            'type' => 'lunch',
            'meal_id' => 5,
            'created_at' => '2021-05-04T20:00:00.000000Z',
            'updated_at' => '2021-05-04T20:00:00.000000Z',
        ],
        'dinner' => [
            'id' => 6,
            'user_id' => 1,
            'day' => 'tuesday',
            'type' => 'dinner',
            'meal_id' => 6,
            'created_at' => '2021-05-04T20:00:00.000000Z',
            'updated_at' => '2021-05-04T20:00:00.000000Z',
        ],
    ],
    // ...
]
```

So you can loop through first level for days and types in that.

Or you can directly check if a meal type of a day exists and use it to fill select boxes

`if(isset(auth()->user()->meals_grouped_by_day_and_type['monday']['lunch'])) { //... }`

Please carefully check the code before use on production. This code always filters only first record of each days each type. For example if you have 2 records for `day=='monday'` and `type='lunch'` it will filter just the first one.

Also this codes uses `$this->userMeals->where(...`, not `$this->userMeals()->where(...`. It means model only queries the database for 1 time and loads it as a collection on `$this->userMeals` so `where()` and `first()` methods works on a `Collection` not on a `QueryBuilder`

If you use it with parentheses like `$this->userMeals()->where(...` it will create a new query for the database and won't be so efficient.

Comment: Great answer! Appreciate the notes on `Collection` vs `QueryBuilder` methods  My only note is that the syntax for Accessors was [changed in Laravel `9.x`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) (vs the [old syntax](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators)). This question isn't tagged for a specific version, but we generally try to link the most up-to-date documentation and recommend that syntax 

Comment: @TimLewis Oh thank you for your kind words and advice on Accessors syntax. I'll update the answer based on this :)

Comment: No problem! You're welcome to leave both syntaxes, since this is valid for older versions, and I think it's still supported (although I haven't verified that). Appreciate the follow-up 

Comment: Amazing answer, and even if this would not work for my project, I am accepting it because it taught me some new things :) Thanks a lot for your contribution as well as everyone else who commented!